# Are African-Americans under-represented in the teaching profession?

Tags: united-states, education, racism

I was doing some research on gaslighting, when I came across the following in the [Gaslighting article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting):

> Gaslighting can be seen as institutional and systematic. An article by Tuesda Roberts and D. Carter Andrews specifically focuses on African-American teachers, and attributes the severely low percentage of African-Americans in the teaching profession to "macro-level and micro-level laws and policies [that] have historically and contemporarily positioned the black educator as 'outsider' and as 'on the margins'", competent to teach Black students but not White students, a form of gaslighting reinforced by "the exodus of White educators from predominantly non-White schools".
>
> Gaslighting as abuse of power and control goes far beyond relationships and into daily struggles. This type of societal gaslighting upon certain capabilities can have a serious effect on personal development. K.E. Portnow terms one form of self-doubt "developmental doubt", and says it is "linked to questions of identity formation in which epistemological complexity potentiated biographical, historical and thematic issues of self-doubt."

What kind of figures are we talking about? I mean what are the actual figures on black american representation as teachers, and what they ought to be given their representation as a whole in the population.

Comment: This seems more like a question for Skeptics.SE. This is also a different definition or use of 'gaslighting' than I've seen in common use.

Comment: I took Gaslighting out of the title, since it's highly misleading. Gaslighting usually means that someone with malicious intent is trying to convince you that events you are observing are signs that you are going insane. The term is derived from the movie [Gaslight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslight_(1944_film)). The base question that it raises is on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.

Comment: This belongs on Academia... if not Quora. The percentage of AA in the US and the percent of those working in academia is a given statistic. Whatever can be otherwise extrapolated from that information is off topic for any SE site.

Answer (score 25):

African-americans are 12.6% of the USA population. [This table](https://nces.ed.gov/pubs2009/2009324/tables/sass0708_2009324_t12n_02.asp) shows the breakdown of teachers for 2007-8, so its a bit out of date, but I doubt that the situation has changed greatly in the last 10 years. At that time 6.7% of teachers were "black, non-Hispanic". While there is no analysis of the correlation between black pupils and black teachers, the figures do show that black teachers are concentrated in city schools in poor areas (see the figures for free and reduced price lunches).

This supports the basic claim of racial disparity in the quoted text.

However the quoted text appears to be stretching the definition of "gaslighting" to breaking point. [Wikipedia's definition of gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) is:

> a form of psychological manipulation that seeks to sow seeds of doubt in a targeted individual or in members of a targeted group, making them question their own memory, perception, and sanity.

The quoted text attributes the low level of African-American teachers to "laws and policies" that have "positioned" them as unsuitable teachers for white pupils. While there is no doubt that American society tells black people that "you cannot succeed because you are black" in many ways, this does not fit the definition of gaslighting because it does not cause the victims to question their own memory, perception or sanity.

Furthermore, if a black teacher is teaching black pupils then this presents those pupils with a successful black role model. This actually counters the "gaslighting" thesis of the quoted text.

Comment: `While there is no analysis of the correlation between black pupils and black teachers, the figures do show that black teachers are concentrated in city schools in poor areas` The former somewhat defeats the latter. If black people themselves are concentrated in poor areas, then it stands to reason that black teachers are concentrated in poor areas as well. Unless you have any evidence to argue that teachers tend to not live in poor areas (e.g. this could easily be proven for CEO's)

Comment: @Flater Only if the figures also show that black **pupils** are *also* concentrated in city schools in poor areas - but, that would then be a "correlation between black pupils and black teachers" so either wasn't examined in the article or is not prevalent enough to be statistically significant.

Comment: `that would then be a "correlation between black pupils and black teachers"` While what you say is technically correct, it implies a direct correlation between black pupils and teachers specifically, which would then not be the case. The same would apply to any profession. Simply put: people like working close to home, for obvious reasons. That's it.

Comment: '...appears to be stretching the definition of "gaslighting" to breaking point...' It's ok. **It's Wikipedia. You can just tell them an editor completely misused the term** and it'll help in the edit war to get it removed/correctly placed.

Comment: Also, I understand the rhetorical thrust of your last paragraph but it's actually only true to the extent that the teachers are doing a good job and seen as such. I would not say that applied to the majority of certified teachers I've had or met in American public education, regardless of color.

Comment: @lly If you are implying that Wikipedia needs to change to fit a definition that supports this as gaslighting, it would stretch Websters definition even further: "to attempt to make (someone) believe that he or she is going insane (as by subjecting that person to a series of experiences that have no rational explanation)" and also Oxford's: Manipulate (someone) by psychological means into doubting their own sanity.

Comment: This quote: `While there is no doubt that American society tells black people that "you cannot succeed because you are black" in many ways` sounds like a quote that would need a source. I don't doubt there's individuals who think that, regardless of whether it's true or not, but it's a rather bold claim that society as a whole tells that to black people. Not down voting because it's validity doesn't undermine your answer.

Comment: The way I can connect the idea of gaslighting as applied to discrimination would be related to the undeniable statistical facts that suggest bias and the general unwillingness of broad portions of society to accept/admit said bias exists.  If you perceive bias against you and are continually seeing messages claiming it does not exist or that the opposite is the real problem (i.e. reverse discrimination), it could be interpreted as gaslighting.  Skimming the original source, it seems to align with this application of the term.

Comment: The question wasn't about the definition of gaslighting. If you disagree with that part of the Wikipedia exposition on the subject, the proper place to express that would be on that Wikipedia page's talk tab, not here.

Comment: Your analysis does not include the percentage of AAs that are skilled enough and applied for teaching roles

Comment: Also which laws the author is referring go unsaid, probably intentionally so.  The 14th Amendment certainly contradicts his claim as do the entire body of law on civil rights beginning in 1954

Comment: While I don't think it would be a significant change, I should put out your statistics for AA teachers vs AA population are not ideal.  Since the teachers statistics is specifically AA who are not Hispanic it is a subset of all AA teachers.  You would need to compare that to the percentage of no Hispanic AA in the US, not the percentage of AA, including Hispanic, in the US to get a fair comparison on representation.

Comment: I tend to think of gaslighting as a tactic that originated on the net as a form of intimidation; that said, the wiki article does mention 'developmental doubt' and questions of 'identify-formation'; so it's not perhaps as much of a stretch as you're claiming; given descriptions I've come across about gaslighting there does seem to be a family resemblence here.